# Rewrite URL for IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I work for an organization which has its intranet on Joomla 3.6.4 and hosted on IIS. 
The company plans to revamp the main menu of the site and hence all the old url's need to be redirected to the new ones.
I tried adding Rewrite Maps and rules via the IIS Manager but no luck.
Any tips or good documentation I can refer to? any help would be greatly received.

Thanks,
Pooja

Comment: IIS.net has all the necessary articles for you to get started.

Comment: http://iirf.codeplex.com/